# Replacing Apple Pushnotification certificates

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an app in the Apple store with pushnotification. The push certificate will end this month, so I need to generate new ones. My plan is this:

1. generate new push certificates
2. remove the old ones from the App ID
3. add the new ones to the App ID
4. Generate new provision certificates (which now includes the new push notification certs)
5. upload to iTunes connect

My main concern is now that when I do steps 2,3 my current app doesn't do receive notifications anymore.

Or is it like, when the push payload is presented to Apple with the current cert, it only checks if the signed push cert is valid, so the app can still receive notifications?

Of course when my new app build is uploaded and live, I need to upload the new p12 certs.

Hope somebody can shed light on this.

Comment: You need to create an updated certificate and replace it at your server for sending push notifications. No need to update App on App Store. Live app will continue to receive push notifications as before.

Comment: ahaa .. I thought I had to rebuild the app again with the new push certs and make it live. Thanx.